# Service is not working as expected

Tags: android, service

I have written one service.It work for Nexus, Samsung, sony and moto but in some phones like Xiaomi, leeco it not work.

When I kill app service get stopped in Xiaomi but it worked in other phones.
I'm not able to figureout the exact issue. 
Can somebody help me to find out. I have just tested in Xiaomi phone and it is not working as expected. Here is my code please try to figure out. 
I have declare in manifest file as well.Thanks

As every said remove location interface.So, i have removed and it sill not work in  background in mi phone.Any solution please suggest.One more things onDestroy of service is not call.When i try to kill app

I have tried other ways also like **alarm manager, job scheduler, broadcast receiver**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private final LocalBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent paramIntent) {
    return this.binder;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public LocalBinder() {
    }
    public MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}
}
```

Comment: which android-versions are on the different android-devices. Do all devices have the same version of google-play-service? As far as i know `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` only works if google-play-service is installed and it requieres a minimum android-api-version.

Comment: Please try to implement this correct interface : com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

Comment: @k3b he is asking about service is not working in background

Comment: I have the same problem that my own LocationListener does not get called on a device that has no google-play services installed

Comment: Yes you are right but my question is service destroyed in some devices that mentioned above

Comment: Location listener isn't a problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Xiaomi use MIUI ROM, and at that ROM user must to set which app will be able to work in background manually.

Comment: Thanks for answer but some of apps are working like whatsapp and other apps

Comment: So is there any way to without go to any settings and it work from code only?

Comment: @Saveen I assume they just added popular apps as default to work in background and not been killed by OS. And I don't think that there is a way to force MUIU to not kill app in background, otherwise it wouldn't have a sense.

Comment: Ok thanks for information.So you prefer something for this problem ?

Comment: @Saveen try to use foreground service. If it won't help - ask user to allow your app in background.